# Second highest column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have seen a similar question asked [How to get second highest value among multiple columns in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877928/how-to-get-second-highest-value-among-multiple-columns-in-sql) ... however the solution won't work for Microsoft Access (Row_Number/Over Partition isn't valid in Access).

My Access query includes dozens of fields. I would like to create a new field/column that would return the second highest value of 10 specific columns that are included in the query, I will call this field "Cover". Something like this:

```
    Product  Bid1    Bid2   Bid3   Bid4  Cover
    Watch    104     120    115    108   115
    Shoe     65      78     79     76    18
    Hat      20      22     19     20    20
```

I can do a really long `SWITCH` formula such as the following equivalent Excel formula:

```
IF( AND(Bid1> Bid2, Bid1 > Bid3, Bid1 > Bid4), Bid1, 
    AND(Bid2> Bid1, Bid2 > Bid3, Bid2 > Bid4), Bid2,
    .....
```

But there must be a more efficient solution. A `MAXIF` equivalent would work perfectly if MS-Access Query had such a function.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: well written question +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier if the data were laid out in a more [normalized way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The clue is the numbered field names.

Your data is currently organized as a [**Pivot**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) (known in Access as [crosstab](https://support.office.com/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8)), but can easily be [**Unpivoted**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47505880/8112776).

This data is much easier to work with if laid in a more *normalized* fashion which is this case would be:

```
  Product   Bid   Amount  
 --------- ----- -------- 
  Watch       1      104  
  Watch       2      120  
  Watch       3      115  
  Watch       4      108  
  Shoe        1       65  
  Shoe        2       78  
  Shoe        3       79  
  Shoe        4       76  
  Hat         1       20  
  Hat         2       22  
  Hat         3       19  
  Hat         4       20
```

This way querying becomes simpler.

It looks like you want the **maximum of the bids, grouped by Product**, so:

```
select Product, max(amount) as maxAmount
from myTable 
group by product
```

Really, we shouldn't be storing text fields at all, so Product should be an ID number, with associated Product Names stored *once* in a separate table, instead of *several times* in the this one, like:

```
  ProdID   ProdName  
 -------- ---------- 
    1       Watch     
    2       Shoe      
    3       Hat
```

... but that's another lesson.

Generally speaking repeating of *anything* should be avoided... that's pretty much the *purpose* of a database... but the links below will explain than I.  :)

---

- Quackit : [**Microsoft Access Tutorial**](//quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/)
- YouTube : [**DB Planning**](https://youtu.be/i72fVNqfWL4)
- Microsoft : [**Database Design Basics**](//support.office.com/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5)
- Microsoft : [**Database Normalization Basics**](//support.microsoft.com/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics)
- Wikipedia : [**Database Normalization**](//enwp.org/Database_normalization)

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much for the insight. Although I would like there to be a magic formula, I think normalizing my data is be the best move. Especially since this database will continue to grow and become more complex over time.